# AttributeError: 'QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'save_statevector'

Tags: qiskit

Hi i know the question was already asked but my case is slightly different.
I am trying to do the qiskit tutorial:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, assemble, Aer
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram, plot_bloch_vector
from math import sqrt, pi

qc = QuantumCircuit(1) # We are redefining qc
initial_state = [0.+1.j/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2)+0.j]
qc.initialize(initial_state, 0)
qc.draw()

qc.save_statevector()
result = sim.run(assemble(qc)).result()
state = result.get_statevector()
print("Qubit State = " + str(state))
```

but i get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [29], in <cell line: 10>()
      7 qc.initialize(initial_state, 0)
      8 qc.draw()
---> 10 qc.save_statevector()
     11 result = sim.run(assemble(qc)).result()
     12 state = result.get_statevector()

AttributeError: 'QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'save_statevector'
```

I know that this is verion dependen but pip show qiskit proofs that i use version 0.36
can somebody pls tell me what else i could try?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens because `save_statevector` is a Qiskit Aer instruction that is added to `QuantumCircuit` class when Aer is imported properly (see the details [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/6346))

Just import `Aer` as follows:

```
from qiskit.providers.aer import Aer
```

Another solution is to import `save_statevector` itself:

```
from qiskit.providers.aer.library import save_statevector
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it

Answer (score 4):

As with so many programming/debugging questions, the accepted answer

> > Just import `Aer` as follows:
> >
> > ```
> > from qiskit.providers.aer import Aer
> > ```

is already stale.

The most recent version of qiskit does not appear to even include an importable qiskit.providers.aer.

An alternative solution to the problem is to make sure that the line

```
sim = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
```

Is called *before* the line

```
qc.save_statevector()
```

See [this discussion](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/6346) for more details about this strange behavior.